# how to fullscreen a Sencha Touch 2 page on a WebKit browser?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

When I visit http://www.wikpic.com/ on my Android-WebKit-browser the page renders on fullscreen, in other words the navigation bar that shows the URL disappear. How can I do that?

I tried this option but it doesn't work:

```
Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyList', {fullscreen: true});
```

This is my app.js code:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    models: [
        'Contacto'
    ],
    stores: [
        'Contactos'
    ],
    views: [
        'MyList'
    ],
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {

    Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyList', {fullscreen: true});
    }

});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [autoMaximize](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.viewport.Default-cfg-autoMaximize) configuration for Viewport:

```
Ext.application({
    viewport: {
        autoMaximize: true
    },
    ...
});
```

Remember though that it may cause some issues (taken from the Sencha docs):

- Orientation change performance is drastically reduced when this is enabled, on all devices.
- On some devices (mostly Android) this can sometimes cause issues when the default browser zoom setting is changed.
- When wrapping your phone in a native shell, you may get a blank screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work when using Chrome on iOS.  Resorted to the solution offered belo but that results in the bottom tabbar being cut-off.  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?231359-Chrome-in-iOS-%28autoMaximize%29

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately these browsers do not make it easy for us to do this. It is why we disabled it by default. I'm unsure of any solution at this time.

Comment: what does autoMaximize actually do? technically-wise, what css/js algorythm does it rely on?

Comment: @SergeySob I believe it hard codes the width and height of the application to the width and height of the window on any size change.