# How do make view port auto-maximize in Sencha touch 2?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to fullscreen a Sencha Touch 2 page on a WebKit browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316314/how-to-fullscreen-a-sencha-touch-2-page-on-a-webkit-browser)

How do you reliably make the viewport take up the entire canvas in Sencha Touch 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
Ext.Viewport.init();
        Ext.create('Ext.Panel'({
            fullscreen:true})
```

added  to your main app file.  This will work if your main view is a panel.  You can also add it as a property of your app:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'YourApp',
    stores: [
    ],
    controllers: [
    ],
    views: [

    ],
    viewport: {
        autoMaximize: true
    },
    launch: function(){

    }
});
```

Comment: new Ext.Panel(...); is not the proper way to create a panel or any other component in ST2. Use Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {...})

Comment: Sry that was some code from ST1. Editing that good looking out!